# Is there a library that provides API compatible to java/android networking in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone, ably-realtime

I am building apps to connect to realtime and streaming services like PubNub, Ably, deep stream.io and XMPP. I am having to port java/android SDKs and the big issue is always around threads and networking. IS there plan to support the JAVA/Android API for network and threads or is there a library providing that? I do not have the skills or time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub has a port to Codename One that's a bit outdated by now. There is support for the URL API but nothing lower level than that as it won't be doable (correctly) on iOS.

I would suggest working with websockets which are very portable and easy to work with: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/introducing-codename-one-websocket-support.html